# WebDriverManager throwing TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, selenium, selenide, webdrivermanager-java

I am trying to replace my local geckodriver.exe with WebDriverManager, but when i invoke

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
```

i get the following error

```
4391 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases to seek geckodriver
4704 [main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing geckodriver (latest version) (Type com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap not present) ... trying again using latest driver stored in cache
4704 [main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Reading https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases to seek geckodriver
4876 [main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing geckodriver (latest version) (Type com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap not present)
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    ...
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.fallback(WebDriverManager.java:825)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:802)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:599)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:287)
```

I am using the latest 5.0.3 WebDriverManager from maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeNotPresentException` is thrown when an application tries to access a type using a string representing the type's name, but no definition for the type with the specified name can be found.

It's pretty similar to `ClassNotFoundException`, but not checked during compilation.

But the root cause is:

`com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap` not present in the project classpath.

Try to add `gson` dependency to the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/TypeNotPresentException.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the [***WebDriverManager***](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/WebDriverManager.java) scope to *`test`* in ***pom.xml*** as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

or change the scope to *`compile`* in ***pom.xml*** as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, you may need to add the ***slf4j*** dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

As per [Driver Management - Feature](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#driver-management):

> Although not mandatory, it is highly recommended to use a logger library to trace your application and tests. In the case of WebDriverManager, you will see the relevant steps of the driver management following its traces. See for example the following tutorial to use [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/). Also, you can see an example of a WebDriverManager test using logging [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/firefox/FirefoxTest.java) (this example uses this [configuration file](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml)).

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [I am getting an error while executing the basic website launch using web driver manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/291)

Comment: i don't have geckodriver() in my WebDriverManager
                                             
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method geckodriver()
  location: class io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager

Comment: @AlexBi Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: this is the source code of WebDriverManager
[https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/WebDriverManager.java](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/WebDriverManager.java)

i just don't see `geckodriver()`  in there

Comment: What do you mean? Where do you see _`geckodriver()`_ now within this answer?

Comment: sorry, i did what you post above and i still getting the same error as the question, was assuming from the previous answer